# Can the Zephyr Blade's Storm Dance Strike be used against an enemy that has forced movement?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement, battlemind

The **`Battlemind`** has a *Paragon path* called **`Zephyr Blade`** that has a `Daily` power called **`Storm Dance Strike.`**

Storm Dance Strike allows the Battlemind to enter into a stance that allows for an **`Opportunity Action.`**

The trigger for the `Opportunity Action` is:

> **Trigger:** An adjacent enemy marked by you moves without shifting

Does that mean if an enemy adjacent to the Battlemind is `pulled`, `pushed`, or `slide`, then the Battlemind can attack with this power?

Does **forced movement** trip the trigger of "moves without shifting"?

Comment: The general rule is "forced movement does not provoke OAs". In this case, it says the enemy "moves", not "is moved".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Forced Movement does not provoke.  Plain and simple.

> **willing movement** 
>   Movement of any sort that a creature does of its own free will. **Any other sort of movement, such as forced movement, is unwilling.**

Since the creature is not moving of its own accord, but compelled to, it won't count.  If the enemy MOVES on ITS turn, then ya, the trigger can go off.

Comment: Would willing teleportation trigger this opportunity action?

Comment: Teleportation is instantaneous and one of the sub-rules is **No Opportunity Actions Triggered**